# Why does Sourcetree open an authentication window for git.heroku.com?

Tags: git, heroku, sourcetree

When I have Sourcetree open, this authentication window will pop up every few minutes:

[image]

I've looked through my accounts in the Sourcetree options, and I can't find anything that looks related to this. I remember a long time ago lookng into Heroku but I don't think I ever got it working. Does anyone have any idea what might cause this to pop up?